# running part of my MainActivty in a separate thread

Tags: android, kotlin, background-process

I am researching ways to run my onResume function in a separate thread or process, so it doesn't block the loading of that activity.

I am looking at ways of running the onResume function i have in my MainActivity separately. What is within the onResume is a collection of routines that loads data back from sharedPref when the app either starts or resumes. However that onResume process delays the whole loading of the activity, so what i am thinking is can it be run from a separate process in order to not delay the loading of the whole activity?

```
package com.taylorworld.tw1

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Context.*
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
//import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.content_main.*
import java.sql.Types.NULL

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),     NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        val intent = Intent(this, Main2Activity::class.java)
        val sharedPref = this?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val mystr = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.STR), 0)
        intent.putExtra("data", mystr)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,     R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    )
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()

    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

    //val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is     present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings -> true
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_home -> {
            // Handle the camera action
            val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,     Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/brobostigon/"))
            startActivity(i)
        }
        R.id.nav_gallery -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_slideshow -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_tools -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_share -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_send -> {

        }
    }
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
}

public fun saveStr(view: View) {
    var strength = Integer.parseInt(editText2.text.toString())
    // this should be getPreferences
    val sharedPref = this?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    with(sharedPref.edit()) {
        putInt(getString(R.string.STR), strength)
        apply()
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Strength Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    //val myRef = database.getReference("str")
    //myRef.setValue(strength)
}

public fun saveDex(view: View) {
    var dexterity = Integer.parseInt(editText.text.toString())
    // this should be getPreferences
    val sharedPref = this?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    with(sharedPref.edit()) {
        putInt(getString(R.string.DEX), dexterity)
        apply()
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Dexterity Saved",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public fun saveInt(view: View) {
    var intelligance = Integer.parseInt(editText4.text.toString())
    // this should be getPreferences
    val sharedPref = this?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    with(sharedPref.edit()) {
        putInt(getString(R.string.INT), intelligance)
        apply()
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Intelligence Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public fun saveWis(view: View) {
    var wisdom = Integer.parseInt(editText3.text.toString())
    // this should be getPreferences
    val sharedPref = this?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    with(sharedPref.edit()) {
        putInt(getString(R.string.WIS), wisdom)
        apply()
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Wisdom Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public fun saveCha(view: View) {
    var charisma = Integer.parseInt(editText5.text.toString())
    // this should be getPreferences
    val sharedPref = this?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    with(sharedPref.edit()) {
        putInt(getString(R.string.CHA), charisma)
        apply()
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "charisma Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public fun saveCon(view: View) {
    var constitution = Integer.parseInt(editText6.text.toString())
    // this should be getPreferences
    val sharedPref = this?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    with(sharedPref.edit()) {
        putInt(getString(R.string.CON), constitution)
        apply()
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Constitution Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public fun saveChr(view: View) {
    var chrname = editText7.text.toString()
    // this should be getPreferences
    val sharedPref = this?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    with(sharedPref.edit()) {
        putString(getString(R.string.CHR), chrname)
        apply()
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Character Name Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        //public fun readSP(view: View) {

        val sharedPref = this?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        val mystr = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.STR), 0);
        editText2.setText(Integer.toString(mystr))

        val mydex = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.DEX), 0);
        editText.setText(Integer.toString(mydex))

        val myint = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.INT), 0);
        editText4.setText(Integer.toString(myint))

        val mywis = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.WIS), 0);
        editText3.setText(Integer.toString(mywis))

        val mycon = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.CON), 0);
        editText6.setText(Integer.toString(mycon))

        val mycha = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.CHA), 0);
        editText5.setText(Integer.toString(mycha))

        val mychr = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.CHR), null);
        editText7.setText(mychr)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use coroutines to load the data in a background thread and then switch back to the UI thread to populate your views, like this (for clarity, I only use 2 properties):

```
data class MyData(
        val myStr: Int,
        val myDex: Int
)

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        val data = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val mystr = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.STR), 0);
            val mydex = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.DEX), 0);
            MyData(mystr, mydex)
        }
        editText2.setText(data.myStr.toString())
        editText.setText(data.myDex.toString())
    }
}
```

However, note that loading preferences is very fast, so I doubt that this is your bottleneck, you may need to do some profiling to see where the time is spent.

Also note that you are mixing `process` and `thread` - your whole app runs in a `process`, and you have multiple `threads` in that process - you can switch threads within your process, but your whole app is a single `process`.

Comment: Ah ok, that looks like a good way of doing, i have made notes and will try it. That is a good point, i have mixed them up, your right, woops. Thats what i thought, it did seem fast at doing it, i will do more testing.

Comment: I have built around what you suggested using coroutines and it works beautifully, :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using kotlin you could also use Anko library that let you execute in background with doAsync{} and return to UI thread

```
// Example from Anko documentation
doAsync {
    // Long background task
    uiThread {
        result.text = "Done"
    }
}
```

Check it: https://github.com/Kotlin/anko